# What's the $z$-derivative of $|g|^2$ for $g(z)$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $g\colon \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic in a domain. What's $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (g \bar{g}).$$
I would think that since $\bar{g}$ is independent of $z$ (it's only dependent on $\bar{z}$), the answer should be
$$ g' \bar{g}.$$

I'm using the standard definition: $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - i \frac{\partial}{\partial y})$.

Answer (score 1):

By Leibniz's rule, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} (g \overline{g}) = \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial z} \overline{g} + g \dfrac{\partial \overline{g}}{\partial z} = g' \overline{g} + 0 = g' \overline{g}$$